# How to change the format of a number in the tooltip with Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I've been trying to find a detailed answer to this. But no luck, so maybe you guys can help me out.

So I'm working on building this chart using Google Scripts. I built the chart in an Index.html file using this.

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart();
```

So I gathered the data, and created a Data Table as such.

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Week');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Build');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'GP');
```

As well as added these options to my chart like so.

```
var options = {'title':'Production',
                   'width':1366,
                   'height':768,
                   'vAxis': {'format': 'currency'}
                   };
```

And the chart shows up wonderfully! But I have one tiny issue. The values held in the "number" data type are actually currency values. But instead of being represented in the tooltip as such, the are represented like regular numbers. They are not separated by commas, no decimal point, and especially no dollar symbol. Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu1G2.png) of what i'm talking about. How would I add these specific customizations to the tooltip. Any ideas?

Thank you guys in advanced for your help!

Sincerely,
Sicariuxs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides a [number formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)

Here, I use the formatter to format the numbers in the second column of the data.
This allows the tooltip to show properly.

I also provide a format in the chart options for the vertical axis, which is separate from the formatter.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': drawChart});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
  data.addRows([
    ['Shoes', 10700],
    ['Sports', -15400],
    ['Toys', 12500],
    ['Electronics', -2100],
    ['Food', 22600],
    ['Art', 1100]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('numberformat_div'));

  // create number formatter
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '$',
    negativeParens: true
  });

  // format data in second column
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  chart.draw(data, {
    vAxis: {
      format: '$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)'
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="numberformat_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help man. I think your code is exactly what I'm looking for. But I still get this [error](https://i.imgur.com/SvjAZSG.png) on `formatter.format(data,1);` I know it's that line of code that messes up too because when I comment it out, then the chart runs fine. But of course without the correct format on the tooltip. Any suggestions?

Comment: my apologies! I got it to work! I messed up somewhere along the lines of your code! But once i corrected it! It worked! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize the tooltip strings and format the strings yourself to present them as currency. Here is how you can do that:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };
```

Then, just pass parameter to tooltip and use the formatMoney function, i.e.
`build_amount.formatMoney(2)`